# Obtain statistics of CPU and memory usage from one cgroup

Tags: python, docker, monitoring, cpu-usage, cgroups

## Context

I have a system in which I have to check periodically usage:

- relative (percents) for `CPU`
- and absolute (GB) for `memory`.

## How it's currently implemented

Language we're using is `python`.

### system-wide `psutil`

For system-wide stats it's trivial since we can use `psutil.cpu_percent()` and `psutil.virtual_memory()`.

### `cgroup` (v1)

The problem is that sometimes the script is run inside container, and then we'd like to monitor usage of particular `cgroup` instead of system-wide statistics.

There's already implementation for `cgroups` in our system which bases on:

- for CPU:

  - `cpu.cfs_period_us`
  - `cpu.cfs_quota_us`
  - `cpuacct.usage`
- for memory:

  - `memory.usage_in_bytes`
  - `memory.limit_in_bytes`

### What I need

Here I need an answer for two questions:

- Is the present implementation based on reading values directly from files ok for `cgroup`?
- If no, are there any tools which supports obtaining such kind of information easily.
- If yes, how can I adapt this solution to `cgroup2`?

### Why current solution doesn't work for `cgroup2`

The main problem I have now is lack of support for `cgroup2` since current implementation is based on nested files structure.

#### `cgroup` on `Ubuntu 20.04`

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
```

#### `cgroup2` on `Ubuntu 22.04`

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep cgroup
cgroup2 /sys/fs/cgroup cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
```

Comment: sooo why not use zabbix, nagios, prometheus, anything existing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems

Comment: This module is part of our existing library we publish for clients. It's one of our features, we had to implement, but at the same time we want our library to not rely on external dependencies if necessary.
Tools like Zabbix are just overkill in this case.